# When we create IPA files with two different xcode versions then is there any difference in ipa files?

Tags: ios, xcode

Trying to understand the Xcode versions impact on building IPA files. Checked multiple responses in stackoverflow and few other sites. But not sure how it impacts.

Comment: Thumb of rule try to create the ipa using latest version of xcode.

Answer (score 0):

There're lots of differences. There are differences in the IPA files if you build your software twice with the *same* copy of Xcode (because there are some timestamps included). Building with a different version of the compiler is often going to generate slightly different output. Building against a different version of the SDK is always going to generate different output. Every version of the Swift library is going to be slightly different. You should absolutely expect differences if you change the version of Xcode.